# Python confining within a range

Tags: python, range

I am working on a problem that tells me to create a program that calculates temperature depending on how many "clicks" on a dial. The temperature starts at 40 and stops and 90 and once it stops it goes back to 40 and starts over.

```
clicks_str = input("By how many clicks has the dial been turned?")
clicks_str = int(clicks_str)

x = 40
x = int(x)

for i in range(1):
    if  clicks_str > 50:
        print("The temperature is",clicks_str -10)
    elif clicks_str < 0:
        print("The temperature is",clicks_str +90)
    else:
        print("The temperature is", x + clicks_str)
```

When I put input 1000 clicks, the temperature naturally goes to 990. I can see that from the code, but how would I make it so the "temperature" is a number in between 40 and 90.

Comment: what does `for i in range(1):` mean to you? I believe you can easily take that out of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be with the fact that you use a range function when you do not know the amount of times you need to modify `clicks_str` until you get a value between temperature 40 and 90. You also print the 'temperature' each time you modify the `clicks_str` but it may not be the right temperature yet (until you get `clicks_str` between 0 and 50)

A better way to address this would be to use a while loop:

```
clicks_str = int(input("By how many clicks has the dial been turned?"))
x = 40

while True:
    if  clicks_str > 50:
        clicks_str -= 50
    elif clicks_str < 0:
        clicks_str += 50
    else:
        print("The temperature is", x + clicks_str)
        break # breaks while loop
```

or even way more simply as fedterzi said in his reply is by using modulus:

```
clicks_str = int(input("By how many clicks has the dial been turned?"))
x = 40

temp = (clicks_str % 50) + x
print("The temperature is {}".format(temp))
```

Comment: so the while loop makes sure that the numbers cycled through are 40-90??

Comment: The while loop in this case will keep running until it encounters a break.  As you can see it will only encounter a break once 0 < clicks_str < 50 which will give you a correct temperature value

Answer (score 4):

If you represent the temperature as a number between 0 and 50 (90-40), you could use the modulo operation and then add 40 to get the original temperature.

```
clicks_str = input("By how many clicks has the dial been turned?")
clicks_str = int(clicks_str)

temp = (clicks_str % 51) + 40
print("The temperature is {}".format(temp))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code could be like this, You didn't need to convert numbers to int and you can make an input to int in one line code:

```
clicks_str = int(input("By how many clicks has the dial been turned?"))

x = 40

if  clicks_str > 50:
    print("The temperature is",clicks_str -10)
elif clicks_str < 0:
    print("The temperature is",clicks_str +90)
else:
    print("The temperature is", x + clicks_str)
```

when you enter clicks_str == 1000 or any value >bigger than 50, you're output comes: `clicks_str -10`